# Is there a linguistic term for "word pairs" where the masculine term is positive but its feminine equivalent is not?

Tags: phrases, terminology, linguistics

The feminine form usually has a neutral to negative range of meanings.

e.g.

- **master**  (“a man who controls things”) x **mistress** (“a woman who is having sex with a married man”)
- **governor** (“the chief executive of a state” x **governess** (“a woman employed in a private household to educate the children”)

Other examples:

- *bachelor* (of Arts, etc) x *spinster*
- *dog* (“you old dog!”) x *bitch*

The term I'm looking for refers to **“pairs of words”** and
I’m not looking for “male chauvinism”, “gender discrimination”, “androcentrism”, “sexism”, misogynism or **any word related to sociology**.

Comment: *Sociolinguistic polarity* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the linguistic term the OP is looking for is **asymmetries**

(with minor corrections)

> [Language and Sex Differences](http://www.lingate.8k.com/serap.html)
>   <sup>Serap Yelkenaç</sup>
>
> ... Moreover, another lexical fields that are taken into account as errors resulting in discrimination in language are marital status, **asymmetries** ( in other words, marked and unmarked forms), jobs and pejorative words about women.
>   [...]
>   For example; even though a *governor* is the one who governs a state, a *governess* means one who looks after children. In addition, a *mistress* is not a ‘female master’ nor a *majorette* a ‘female major’. For instance, while Mary is called ‘Tom's mistress’, Tom is not called ‘Mary's master’. You can say Mary is ‘Tom's widow’; whereas, you can not say Tom is ‘Mary's widower’.

The same term is used in [An Introduction to Sociolinguistics](https://books.google.it/books?id=0b0WBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=linguistics%20term%20word%20pairs%20gender%20asymmetries&source=bl&ots=n5jiP-NA5b&sig=COHKn1ikAeDrn-iGdIT5UweuKSs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6yJeVbDHBIGeygPlvYCQAg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=linguistics%20term%20word%20pairs%20gender%20asymmetries&f=false)
<sup>By Ronald Wardhaugh, Janet M. Fuller</sup>

> We can see this in some **asymmetries of pairs of words**. While *actor* and *actress* or *waiter* and *waitress* have few, if any, differences in connotation aside from sex, pairs of terms such as *master—mistress*, *governor—governess*, and *bachelor—spinster* are different in more ways than simply indicating male and female. While a *master* is the man in charge, the word *mistress* is commonly used to refer to the female lover of a married man. [...] While *bachelor* has connotations of fun and independence (as in the term *bachelor pad*) *spinster* is an undeniably negative term, calling up the image of an elderly woman living alone with lots of cats.) The interesting thing thing to note about these **asymmetries**, however, is that probably most readers of this text do not use words *mistress*, *governess*, or *spinster* at all. If they knew  these words, they may not be familiar with the connotations cited here, as societal changes have made these terms less prominent and relevant, especially for young people today.

Further examples taken from a paper entitled
[Language and Gender](http://www.eolss.net/sample-chapters/c04/e6-20b-09-01.pdf)
<sup>By Suzanne Romaine</sup>

> 2.1. **Asymmetries**
>
> ... *Sir* is still used as a title and a form of respect, while a *madam* is
>   one who runs a brothel [...] In italian the related word *maestro* can
>   mean a ‘schoolmaster’ as well as a ‘great teacher’, whereas the feminine
>   form *maestra* refers to a ‘schoolmistress’. There is considerable
>   discrepancy between referring to someone as an *old master* as opposed to
>   an *old mistress*.

Comment: Oh that simple! I was thinking of a more complicated term :) +1